# Regex for validation on streetnames

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'am working on a regex for streetname validation but i got one problem, I need to validate all the character but i can't validate nonsense!

This is my regex:

```
/^[']{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]+[a-zA-Z]{0,1}$/
```

This is what I want it to validate:

```
's-gravenhaeghestraat 12
street 1a
'street 2
```

this is what I don't want to validate:

```
@$%#%*@ 1a
```

Does anybody know how to validate the following without validating nonsense?
's-gravenhaeghestraat 12

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Where do you live that street name starts with `'`?

Comment: I am living in the Netherlands

Comment: What is the purpose of that validation? What if one types `A street name that certainly does not exist` street name? In what way is it better than `@$%#%*@`?

Comment: You need to refer to the rules for street-naming. Oh, there aren't any.

Comment: i would never validate street names.

Comment: You've got a point! The only thing I can do is checking if the input is filled with some characters. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Dedmen7 found somethinge for this?

Comment: No there is no general regex for street name validation

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be beautiful, this matches what you requested.

```
([a-zA-Z-'][[:blank:]]?)+[a-z0-9]+
```

Comment: Sorry but this regex doesn't work for  's-gravenhaeghestraat 12 anyways Thanks for helping!